# Variable content is not saved in the function

Tags: javascript

I have a problem that I can't find a solution for.
In my code there is a variable called `list`.
The variable `list` is supposed to retrieve input elements using `getElementsByName()`, 
but this variable is empty (i.e. `list.length == 0`) after the `if` statement
has ended.
In the code below, at the beginning of the `for` loop the `list.length` is zero or undefined.

Why does this happen?

The function is:

```
function chekRadioToAnswer() {
    var signAnswers = new Array(0, 0, 0, 0);
    var grades = [[0, 5, 10, 15], [15, 12, 10, 5, 0], [0, 5, 10, 15, 20], [0, 0, 20, 30]];
    var answers = new Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    for (num = 2; num <= 5; num++) {
        if (num == 2) {
            list = document.getElementsByName("answer2"); 
        }
        if (num == 3) {
            list = document.getElementsByName("answer3"); 
        }
        if (num == 4) {
            list = document.getElementsByName("answer4"); 
        }
        if (num == 5) {
            list = document.getElementsByName("answer5"); 
        }

        for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if (list[i].checked) {
                var value = document.getElementById("hiddenAnswers").getAttribute("value");
                 document.getElementById("hiddenAnswers").setAttribute("value", (value + grades[num - 2][i]));
                 break;
             }
        }

        list.length = 0;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your are trying to create an array of inputs you need to first declare list and assign it an empty array:

```
var list = [];
```

and then use `push` to add to the array:

```
//If you are going to use getElementsByName, take the first member of the array

var rdo = document.getElementsByName("answer3");

for (var x = 0; x < rdo.length; x++){
  if (rdo[x].checked){
    list.push(rdo[x]);
  }
}
```

Comment: if you can tell me why you want to build a 2d array I'll upvote you. I really cant see a reason to do that at all...

Comment: That is not a 2d array...  Why do you think I am declaring a 2d array?

Comment: `list.push([some,array])` => `list = [[some,array]]`. getElementsByName returns an array

Comment: I see sorry I thought it was `getElementById` not `getElementsByName` will edit...

Comment: Hmm... this still doesn't look right. The word `checked` in the for loop tells us something important about the nature of the input elements. You are suggesting that if the user didn't check the first box/radio button then their input should be thrown away

Comment: @Sheena actually on second thought a 2d array may make sense since it appears radio buttons are being used so it will be necessary to loop over them to see which one is checked.

Comment: But then you are assuming that we want to hang onto the values past their useful life... The fact that `list.length=0` happens after the for loop shows us that we are explicitly throwing the guts away. Each answer array is used once then chucked.

Comment: @Sheena I changed it to loop over the radio buttons and only push the ones that are checked.  Now the nested for loop in not needed.

Answer (score -1):

`whatever = document.getElementsByName(name)` assigns an empty array to `whatever` if no elements of the given name are found. Make sure that your element names are correct.

Also it is good to declare variables with the `var` keyword. This prevents many spooky errors.